# Construct new array of objects from object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of objects from an api, containing latitude and longitude I need to store to another array of objects.

```
response: [
  {
    title: "Map marker 1",
    lat: 10.0,
    lng: 10.0
  },
  {
    title: "Map marker 2",
    lat: 11.0,
    lng: 11.0
  }
]
```

What's the preferred way to get `lat` and `lng` values and store them to a new object array with the following structure?

```
markers: [
   {
     position: {lat: 10.0, lng: 10.0}
   }, 
   {
     position: {lat: 11.0, lng: 11.0}
   }
]
```

Comment: `.map()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map Also, do at least some basic research before posting here...

Comment: No, .map() is not needed.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Care to elaborate?

Comment: There is such a big push to use `.map(), .reduce()` etc. when they are not necessary. `Array.prototype.forEach()` is ideal for this use case. In large applications with large datasets `.map(), .reduce()` etc. are much slower than a traditional for loop **when** working with simple data structures such as this. But whatevs.

Comment: I'm with @RandyCasburn, and if you don't need the old response, you can modify it in place (e.g.:  https://gist.github.com/spelcaster/3029f8c134533ea83fde53c237896bbb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is probably the most obvious way. It will allow you to transform each array element to the shape you want.

```js
let response = [
  {
    title: "Map marker 1",
    lat: 10.0,
    lng: 10.0
  },
  {
    title: "Map marker 2",
    lat: 11.0,
    lng: 11.0
  }
];

let markers = response.map(r => {
  return {
     position: {lat: r.lat, lng: r.lng}
   }
});

console.log(markers);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
response = [
  {
    title: "Map marker 1",
    lat: 10.0,
    lng: 10.0
  },
  {
    title: "Map marker 2",
    lat: 11.0,
    lng: 11.0
  }
];

markers = [];

for (var i in response) {
  markers.push({position: {lat: response[i].lat, lng: response[i].lng}});
}

// Some programmers hate the loop upstairs, so you can do like this and have exactly the same result:
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  markers.push({position: {lat: response[i].lat, lng: response[i].lng}});
}

// Other programmers believe and I don't know why that map is better, so:
markers = response.map(function (item) {
  return {position: {lat: item.lat, lng: item.lng}};
});

// The world is full of boring people, so we have programmers that think that only ECMA6 works, so:
markers = response.map(item => {position: {lat: item.lat, lng: item.lng});

// With any of those codes you will have this:
markers = [
  {
    position: {lat: 10.0, lng: 10.0}
  }, 
  {
    position: {lat: 11.0, lng: 11.0}
  }
]
```

Comment: I think a better approach is using `for-of-loop`

Comment: Why would someone downvote this? It is completely valid code that works. It is because it isn't sexy with `.map()`? This will be the more performant code of any answer provided! JSPerf it to find out yourselves.

Comment: I adjust to please everyone... Why the people are so boring?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `Array.from`

```js
var response = [  {    title: "Map marker 1",    lat: 10.0,    lng: 10.0  },  {    title: "Map marker 2",    lat: 11.0,    lng: 11.0  }],
    markers = Array.from(response, ({lat, lng}) => ({position: {lat, lng}}));

console.log(markers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

The fastest (performance) approach is using `for-loop`

```js
var response = [  {    title: "Map marker 1",    lat: 10.0,    lng: 10.0  },  {    title: "Map marker 2",    lat: 11.0,    lng: 11.0  }],
    markers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  markers[i]   = {position: { lat: response[i].lat, lng: response[i].lng }};
}

console.log(markers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with the values by using a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) of the wanted properties and then take [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for the new object.

```js
var response = [{ title: "Map marker 1", lat: 10.0, lng: 10.0 }, { title: "Map marker 2", lat: 11.0, lng: 11.0 }],
    array = response.map(({ lat, lng }) => ({ position: { lat, lng } }));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```